# Wrong scene size with Scene Animation

Tags: java, android, android-transitions

In my app, I use a `Fragment`in which I want to animate multiple `Scene`s. In my `onCreateView`, I create the frame where `Scene`will be animated with `myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout,null,false)`. The corresponding layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/MyContainer"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@android:color/black"
          android:orientation="vertical">
```

After that :

- I get the frame with `myFrame=(LinearLayout)myView.findViewById(R.id.MyContainer);`.
- I create the `View`for my `Scene`with `activeView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_scene,myFrame,false);` (see the xml file below).
- I create the `Scene`with `myScene =new Scene(myFrame, activeView);`
  .

and I start a `Transition`with `TransitionManager.go(myScene , myTransition);`
.

The layout for the `Scene`is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/InterfaceJeu"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/fond_interface"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context=".Jeu">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TitreJeux"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"/>

<vd63.jeux.Jeu.BoutonInterface
    android:id="@+id/BoutonJouer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bouton_jouer"
    android:text="@string/BoutonJouer"
    android:textColor="@color/CouleurTexteBoutons"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif"/>

<vd63.jeux.Jeu.BoutonInterface
    android:id="@+id/BoutonOptions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bouton_jouer"
    android:text="@string/BoutonOptions"
    android:textColor="@color/CouleurTexteBoutons"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif"/>

<vd63.jeux.Jeu.BoutonInterface
    android:id="@+id/BoutonModeEmploi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bouton_jouer"
    android:text="@string/BoutonModeEmploi"
    android:textColor="@color/CouleurTexteBoutons"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif"/>

<vd63.jeux.Jeu.BoutonInterface
    android:id="@+id/BoutonStatistiques"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bouton_jouer"
    android:text="@string/BoutonStatistiques"
    android:textColor="@color/CouleurTexteBoutons"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif"/>

<vd63.jeux.Jeu.BoutonInterface
    android:id="@+id/BoutonQuitter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bouton_quitter"
    android:text="@string/BoutonQuitter"
    android:textColor="@color/CouleurTexteBoutons"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif"/>
```

The problem is that despite my frame and the `Scene`'s container are defined with width and height set to `match_parent`, the resulting display doesn't always fit the entire screen. On my tablet, only half the screen is used...

Does anyone knows where the problem could come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the line `myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout,null,false)`. Once replaced by `myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout,container,false)`, where `container` is the `Container` passed to the `onCreateView` function as parameter, everything went normal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define separate layout folders to support different devices like below ...

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets
```

Comment: Was rather doubtful but tried it nevertheless (why should I need to do this because  `match_parent` has the same meaning, no matter the screen size or density?). Result : no change...